# How to get the title and url in html page with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I want to go to `department` and only want to select/print the `name` and `url`. I have tried the following but I am unable to understand how to go in `department` and select those 2 specific things. How can I get the "name" and "url" for all the links?

```
import json
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def getContent():
    # target site url
    url = "www.xyz.com"
    # requesting the url for data
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    # get the html, whole page
    htmlpage = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    bsoup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage, "html.parser")
    # print(bsoup.prettify())

    # main_table = bsoup.find("div",attrs)
    # print(main_table)
    # print(bsoup.find_all('name'))
    # nav = bsoup.nav
    # print(bsoup.title.department.url)
    # for url in find_all('a'):
    # print(url.get('href'))

    for link in bsoup.find_all("a"):
        print("Title: {}".format(link.get("name")))
        print("href: {}".format(link.get("href")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `name` / `url` using the `json` module as follows:

```
import json
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_content():
    url = "http://www.ucdenver.edu/pages/ucdwelcomepage.aspx"
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')

    json_data = json.loads(soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json").string)
    for data in json_data["department"]:
        print("{:<60} {}".format(data["name"], data["url"]))

get_content()
```

Output:

```
Center for Undergraduate Exploration and Advising            https://www.ucdenver.edu/center-for-undergraduate-exploration-and-advising
Commencement                                                 https://www.ucdenver.edu/commencement
Counseling Center                                            https://www.ucdenver.edu/counseling-center
First Year Experiences                                       https://www.ucdenver.edu/first-year-experiences
Health Programs                                              https://www.ucdenver.edu/programs/health-programs
Housing and Dining                                           https://www.ucdenver.edu/housing-and-dining
...
```

Comment: may I ask what does "soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json").string" do ? why cannot I directly do something like department.name?

Comment: @Poala This find the JSON data on the website. See the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) for the `find()` method.